# Flutter: Quiz App a method to not repeat same questions

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, multiplatform

So in short
A questions as shown below has a unique qnumber and i dont want the same question to repeat until all the question in said json file for the chosen category is answered once.

```
  {
    "category": 9,
    "type": "multiple",
    "qnumber": 1,
    "difficulty": "any",
    "question": "Which of the following is a programming language?",
    "correct_answer": "Python",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Latin", "Swahili", "Mandarin"]
  },
```

so i tried to implement flutter hive package to store the shown questions qnumber. im a novice coder so that didnt work. that quiz app works for 10 to 5 questions but the same questions keep repeating and new once are not being shown. that keeps being a problem. this is an exam app that need to be able to show all questions 10-25-50-75-100 questions at a time but the same questions being the problem needs to stop repeating.

my knowledge states i need to add a trigger code for the qnumber to be stored when user submits the quiz session.

here are the relevant code. the quiz data code. in short it exacts the questions from json file and forward it to the questions provider.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../model/question.dart';

Future<List<Question>> getQuestionsFromJson(
    {int? categoryId, int? totalQuestions}) async {
  final String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/quiz.json');
  List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(data);

  if (categoryId != null) {
    json = json.where((result) => result['category'] == categoryId).toList();
  }

  if (totalQuestions != null && json.length > totalQuestions) {
    json.shuffle();
    json = json.sublist(0, totalQuestions);
  }

  return json.map((result) {
    return Question(
      category: result['category'],
      type: result['type'],
      qnumber: result['qnumber'],
      difficulty: result['difficulty'],
      question: result['question'],
      correctAnswer: result['correct_answer'],
      incorrectAnswers: List<String>.from(result['incorrect_answers']),
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

here is the question provider. in short it forwards a fixed amount of questions that is asked by the user through a pop menu i named quiz bottom screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/question.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/service/quiz_data.dart';

class QuestionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late List<Question> listQuestion;
  late bool isLoading;
  late String error;
  late int currentIndex;
  late Map<int, dynamic> answer;

  void initValue() {
    listQuestion = [];
    isLoading = false;
    error = '';
    currentIndex = 0;
    answer = {};
  }

  Future<List<Question>> getDataQuestion(
    String difficulty,
    int totalQuestion,
    int categoriesId,
  ) async {
    try {
      listQuestion = await getQuestionsFromJson();
      listQuestion = listQuestion
          .where((question) =>
              question.difficulty == difficulty &&
              question.category == categoriesId)
          .toList();

      print(categoriesId);
      print(totalQuestion);
      print(difficulty);
      print(listQuestion.length);
    } catch (e) {
      error = 'Unable to read data';
    }
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return listQuestion;
  }

  void selectRadio(dynamic e) {
    answer[currentIndex] = e;
    notifyListeners();
    return;
  }

  void selectQuestion(dynamic e) {
    currentIndex = e;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void previousQuestion() {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      currentIndex--;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> submitQuiz(List<Question> listQuestion) async {
    if (currentIndex < (listQuestion.length - 1)) {
      currentIndex++;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void isLoadingg(bool status) {
    isLoading = status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

here is the quiz bottom screen code. in short a user is prompted to select difficulty and number of questions they want for the quiz. yah this is a big one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/question.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/provider/question_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/screen/quiz_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/util/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/widget/snackbar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class QuizBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int id;

  const QuizBottomSheet({Key? key, required this.title, required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizBottomSheetState createState() => _QuizBottomSheetState();
}

class _QuizBottomSheetState extends State<QuizBottomSheet> {
  int selectNumber = 10;
  String selectDifficult = "Any";
  late String selectType;
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Select Total Number of Questions"),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildNumberQuestion(10),
                _buildNumberQuestion(20),
                _buildNumberQuestion(30),
                _buildNumberQuestion(40),
                _buildNumberQuestion(50),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Select Difficulty"),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Any"),
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Easy"),
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Medium"),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Center(child: Consumer<QuestionProvider>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, QuestionProvider value,
                  Widget? child) {
                // add "?" to "Widget"
                return value.isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : Visibility(
                        visible: value.isLoading ? false : true,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => _startQuiz(value),
                          child: Text(
                            "Start Quiz",
                            style: kHeadingTextStyleAppBar.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
              },
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildNumberQuestion(int number) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectNumber = number;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(5, 5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(-5, -5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Color(0xffb8bfce).withOpacity(.1),
            ),
          ],
          color:
              selectNumber == number ? kItemSelectBottomNav : Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        child: Text(
          number.toString(),
          style: selectNumber == number
              ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
              : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildDifficultQuestion(String difficult) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectDifficult = difficult;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 70,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(5, 5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(-5, -5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Color(0xffb8bfce).withOpacity(.1),
            ),
          ],
          color: selectDifficult == difficult
              ? kItemSelectBottomNav
              : Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            difficult,
            style: selectDifficult == difficult
                ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _startQuiz(QuestionProvider value) async {
    if (selectDifficult != null && selectNumber != null) {
      value.isLoadingg(true);
      List<Question> listQuestion = await value.getDataQuestion(
        selectDifficult.toLowerCase(),
        selectNumber,
        widget.id,
      );

      if (listQuestion.length < selectNumber) {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                "Not enough questions available for the selected category and difficulty"));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        value.initValue();
      } else {
        value.initValue();
        Navigator.pop(context); // close show bottom sheet
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => QuizPage(
              difficult: selectDifficult,
              id: widget.id,
              listQuestion: listQuestion.take(selectNumber).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        elevation: 5.0,
        content: Text(
          'Please choose option!',
        ),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
}
```

and finally this is the quiz screen code.

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/question.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/provider/question_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/provider/score_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/screen/quiz_finish_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/util/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/util/router_path.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/widget/awesomedialog.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/widget/snackbar.dart';
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/categories.dart';

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Question> listQuestion;
  final int id;
  final String difficult;

  const QuizPage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.listQuestion,
      required this.id,
      required this.difficult})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<ScoreProvider>(context, listen: false).getAllScore();
    print(widget.listQuestion.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> listQuestionNumber = List<int>.generate(
        widget.listQuestion.length, (i) => i); // convert array to int

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onBackPress,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: kItemSelectBottomNav,
            elevation: 0.0,
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                buildDialog(
                    context,
                    "Warning!",
                    'Do you want to cancel this quiz? ',
                    DialogType.WARNING,
                    () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    () => null);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  categories
                      .firstWhere((category) => category.id == widget.id)
                      .name,
                  style: kHeadingTextStyleAppBar.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Difficult: ${widget.difficult}",
                  style: kHeadingTextStyleAppBar.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ClipPath(
                clipper: MyClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  height: 280,
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 50),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: kItemSelectBottomNav),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Consumer<QuestionProvider>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, QuestionProvider value,
                        Widget? child) {
                      Question question =
                          widget.listQuestion[value.currentIndex];
                      final List<dynamic> listOptions =
                          question.incorrectAnswers;
                      if (!listOptions.contains(question.correctAnswer)) {
                        listOptions.add(question.correctAnswer);
                        listOptions.shuffle();
                      }
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ...listQuestionNumber
                                    .map((e) => SingleChildScrollView(
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              value.selectQuestion(e);
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 15, right: 10),
                                              child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  color: value.currentIndex == e
                                                      ? Colors.grey[200]
                                                      : Color(0xff7146ff),
                                                ),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      e.toString(),
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color:
                                                              value.currentIndex ==
                                                                      e
                                                                  ? Colors.black
                                                                  : Colors
                                                                      .white,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )),
                              ],
                            ),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              HtmlUnescape().convert(widget
                                  .listQuestion[value.currentIndex].question),
                              style: kHeadingTextStyleAppBar.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        offset: Offset(10, 10),
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 126, 126, 126),
                                      ),
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ...listOptions.map(
                                        (e) => RadioListTile(
                                          groupValue:
                                              value.answer[value.currentIndex],
                                          activeColor: Colors.red,
                                          title:
                                              Text(HtmlUnescape().convert(e)),
                                          onChanged: (abc) {
                                            value.selectRadio(e);
                                          },
                                          value: e,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (value.currentIndex == 0) {
                                    SnackBars.buildMessage(context,
                                        "You are already at the first question!");
                                  } else {
                                    value.previousQuestion();
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Text("Back"),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (value.answer[value.currentIndex] ==
                                      null) {
                                    SnackBars.buildMessage(
                                        context, "Please check the answer!");
                                  } else if (value.currentIndex ==
                                      widget.listQuestion.length - 1) {
                                    SnackBars.buildMessage(context,
                                        "You have reached the last question!");
                                  } else {
                                    value.submitQuiz(widget.listQuestion);
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Text("Next"),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  buildDialog(
                                    context,
                                    "Finish?",
                                    "Are you sure you want to finish the quiz?",
                                    DialogType.success,
                                    () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (_) => QuizFinishPage(
                                          title: categories
                                              .firstWhere((category) =>
                                                  category.id == widget.id)
                                              .name,
                                          answer: value.answer,
                                          listQuestion: widget.listQuestion,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    () => null,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Text("Submit"),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> onBackPress() {
    return buildDialog(context, "Warning!", 'Do you want to cancel this quiz? ',
        DialogType.WARNING, () => Navigator.pop(context, true), () => null);
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    // TODO: implement getClip
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 40);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 4, size.height, size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - (size.width / 4), size.height,
        size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

someone please help.

Comment: How often are the question repeated? Does the question repeat after each other or they repeat at random?

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's a LOT of code for us to parse through and the core issue sounds more logic or overall app design related that code related. If you don't want questions repeated, you'll need to track which have been asked, so your initial thinking was on point. However, app design questions go beyond what we can help with here on SO; this site is for code specific questions. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Franknike its just repeats ar random i seem to have no control over it.

Comment: @Jay i understand and appreciate the feedback you have brought forward. I just couldnt have explained it in a better way or a shorter way than this. For that i apologize.